# Windows 10 boot takes 9 minutes on an SSD. The culprit appears to be in the Session Init but I can't find the issue

Tags: windows-10, boot, performance-monitor

My windows machine has started booting very slowly. I initially thought my storage HDD was failing but removing it hasn't resolved the issue. I tried clean booting, cleaning the registry, removing old drivers and a whole host of other things suggested online but nothing has had a measurable impact.

Once the computer boots it runs perfectly, I played a couple of hours of Elden Ring and no issues whatsoever so I don't think it's hardware related (but happy to be proven wrong on that!)

I ran the boot analysis using the performance tool and I have uploaded the ETL. If anyone with the knowledge could take a look to see where the issue might be I'd really appreciate it.

The file is [linked here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JKzQ5emJztbpI0S6SC3kmfV23fmh-rRg/view?usp=share_link)

Many thanks

Comment: you may want to try the MS Memory diagnostics. I recall a simmillar issue some years ago that ended up being bad ram.

Comment: Thanks @FrankThomas I just did the memory check but no errors found

Comment: Run MSCONFIG and limit (greatly) what starts up. What happens?

Comment: @John thanks but have tried that, limiting to only the base Microsoft services. Made no difference at all. I've always been good at keeping the startup services light anyway.

Comment: I suggest now running hardware tests on your SSD. If not memory, and not startup items, then the SSD may have issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another user messaged me directly with the feedback from the ETL analysis. Would appear that the registry was corrupted somehow, most of the time in boot was registry operations. I tried to get to the root of it but no luck so I just backed up my data and reinstalled windows. Even trying a reset operation from Windows failed every time, so a full format of the drive and reinstall of the OS was needed. All good now, so closing the question.